# jQuery UI -- buttonset buttons don't always work on first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery UI buttonset (based on a few radio buttons.) Everything works pretty fine except sometimes when you click on one of the buttons nothing happens (just as if you had never clicked it at all). I thought perhaps it was perhaps a problem with my implementation so I went to the demo site:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

And spent some time clicking around flipping between the different choices. I had the same problem! Randomly the click would be ignored!

I came across this site:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Which rolled their own version and I was unable to replicate the same issue. Which leads me to believe that there is some minor quirk with the jQuery UI implementation?

Has anyone seen this? I spent some time trying to find others having the same problem and haven't found any mention of it. Does anyone else see the same issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens for me too.

I think the problem is that you have to hold your mouse still when clicking the button, or it will not work.

For example, try clicking the button while moving your mouse at a slow, steady pace. The button won't work unless the mouse is barely moving. Also try dragging the button even just one pixel, then releasing.

The site you came across that works seems to use `mousedown` to avoid this problem. They are also using an older version of jQuery UI, which might be a factor.

Comment: Same here, it's terrible!  Is there a jquery bug on this?

Comment: @NadirMuzaffar I think this is a better bug request to capture the details: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7665

Answer (score 7):

```
 $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
 $( "#radio" ).find("label").unbind("mouseup");
```

because in jquery source code there is:

```
.bind( "mouseup" + this.eventNamespace, function( event ) {
  if ( options.disabled ) {return; }
  if ( startXPos !== event.pageX || startYPos !== event.pageY ) {
                    clickDragged = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this workaround - it works: when I move mouse  while clicking, button state is still switched.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked well for Chrome and IE, but while reading a link posted above I noticed a comment in [link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7665) that this has to do with the behavior of Firefox in particular.  In testing I found that the unbind work around seems to have strange and adverse effects in Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately, on Firefox all this did was create the illusion that it worked (input graphic changes but doesn't trigger change event)